# Django TemplateTags not compiling

Tags: python, django, templatetags, django-oscar

I am trying to create custom django templatetags for my project. I followed the guides available and created the tags. But the tags are not being picked up.
They aren't even being compiled (as the `.pyc` file isn't generated).

The structure is `my_dir>app>templatetags>markup_tags.py`. The folders `app` and `templatetags` have the required `__init__.py` file.

My markup_tags.py file is

```
from django import template
from random import randint

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag()
def random_number(length=3):
    """
    Create a random integer with given length.
    For a length of 3 it will be between 100 and 999.
    For a length of 4 it will be between 1000 and 9999.
    """
    return randint(10**(length-1), (10**(length)-1))
```

When I check the tag using `python manage.py shell` command:

```
from my_dir.app.templatetags import markup_tags
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named templatetags
```

Whats wrong here? Thanks.

Edit: The folder structure is
[image: Folder-Structure]

Comment: Do you have an ``__init__.py`` in the ``templatetags`` package/directory?

Comment: @JamesMills Yes, the `templatetags` directory includes a blank `__init__.py` file.

Comment: And all parent directories/packages leading up to the final module?

Comment: @JamesMills not sure what that means. But the `app` in question is being used by my project (the models in the app specifically are used). I also created a new app in the project for the tags but the tags folder isn't being picked up there either.

Comment: Could you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30634805/edit) your question and include ``sys.path`` and a ``pstree`` of your app/folder structure?

Comment: What happens if you type the command without `my_dir`, like this: `from app.templatetags import markup_tags`?

Comment: If you create a separate app for these templatetags, is it in your installed apps? And all other required files to be recognized as a Django app?

Comment: @JamesMills have added the pstree. The entire project is running on `virtualenv` so the sys.path is not an issue.

Comment: @xyres I get `ImportError: No module named app.templatetags`.

Comment: @Blackeagle52 yes i set it up in my `INSTALLED_APPS`. Plus the files in the new app like models.py are being compiled (resulting in *.pyc) but the templatetags folder is being ignored.

Comment: Whoops sorry I meant ``tree`` :) What was I thinking :) *sigh*

Comment: @JamesMills have uploaded the folder tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't know what went wrong but the `templatetags` folder I was copying into the app directory wasn't being picked up by python. I deleted that and using my IDE (`PyCharm`), I created a new `Python Package` in my app, which automatically generates a new `__init__.py` file.

I restarted my server then and it seems to work now. Weird though!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before I solved it by adding code  below

In settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = ('django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
)
```

Add your app in

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ('myapp',)
```

And be sure to have an

```
__init__.py
```

in the "myapp" folder as well as in templatetags.